# Setting home page for Edge browser in Windows Mobile 10

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-10-mobile, kiosk-mode, lockdown

I'm locking down Windows Mobile 10 device and even though it proves to be a challenging task I'm almost there.

The only bit left is either setting Microsoft Edge to use desired URL as a home page or pinning a shortcut (tile) to that URL onto the screen. The later can be done, however, the shortcut is being removed on every reboot, so that's not the solution.

[Windows Configuration Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-install-icd) has an option to choose so called *first run URL*, but there is no option to choose home page URL.

Then there is an option to import your own [XML lockdown file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/configuration/mobile-devices/lockdown-xml#add-lockdown-xml-to-a-provisioning-package) with custom settings, but unfortunately only a few settings defined in it are working or working as expected.

There's not enough documentation on this matter IMO, but I just tried to use [CSPRunner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/configuration/mobile-devices/lockdown-xml#csprunner) string in the lockdown file that should set the home page for the Edge as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/deploy/available-policies)

```
<CSPRunner>
    <SyncML xmlns="SYNCML:SYNCML1.2">
        <SyncBody>
            <Replace>
                <CmdID>1</CmdID>
                <Item>
                    <Target>
                        <LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Browser/HomePages</LocURI>
                    </Target>
                    <Meta>
                        <Format xmlns="syncml:metinf">chr</Format>
                    </Meta>
                    <Data>http://mycustomurl.com/</Data>
                </Item>
            </Replace>
            <Final/>
        </SyncBody>
    </SyncML>
</CSPRunner>
```

As you rightly guessed - it simply doesn't work. Overall, as I said already, some settings are being picked up from the lockdown file and some are not.

The OS version is 1607 so it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a working way of setting the home page for Edge browser, so as an alternative I've created an app with a `WebView` and allowed it to be run in [AssignedAccess.xml file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/mobile-devices/lockdown-xml#full-lockdownxml-example).